# Check if modeless dialogue is already open in C#, Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to open a dialogue box upon clicking a picture, but I also don't want the user to be able to open one if one is already open.

I would also like it to be modeless (they can use the main GUI while the secondary dialogue is still open in the background)

```
private void pictureBox18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ADCs ADCsdiag = new ADCs();
            ADCsdiag.Show();
        }
```

In this example, I can open as many `ADCsdiag` dialogues as I want by clicking the picture. I would like to limit to opening one or no dialogues of this type.

Comment: The way I handle this is by adding a `FormsCollection` class.  In any `Form` that I want to limit to one instance, I will add it to the `FormsCollection`, and then in the `Disposed` method, remove it from the `FormsCollection`.  If I want to limit to one instance, I simply check if the `Form` exists in the `FormsCollection`.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Be sure to upvote and/or accept an answer if you are satisfied with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the `FormsCollection` class that I mentioned in my comment:

```
public class FormsCollection : IEnumerable
{
    private Collection c = new Collection();

    public Form Item {
        get { return c.Item(index); }
    }

    public void Add(Form frm)
    {
        c.Add(frm);
    }

    public virtual IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return c.GetEnumerator;
    }

    public void Remove(Form frm)
    {
        int itemCount = 0;

        for (itemCount = 1; itemCount <= c.Count; itemCount++) {
            if (object.ReferenceEquals(frm, c.Item(itemCount))) {
                c.Remove(itemCount);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will need to instantiate a `FormsCollection` somewhere, then in `Form_Load`, add it to the collection like so:

```
formsCollection.Add(this);
```

and in `Disposed`:

```
formsCollection.Remove(this);
```

This will allow you to `Activate` the `Form` if it is already loaded, rather than opening a new instance.

```
if (FormLoaded(yourForm.Name))
{
    yourForm.Activate()
}
else
{
    yourForm.Show()
}
```

Here is the `FormLoaded` function:

```
public bool FormLoaded(string strFormName)
{
    bool functionReturnValue = false;
    foreach (Form f in Forms) {
        if (f.Name == strFormName) {
            functionReturnValue = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return functionReturnValue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Define it outside of the method, and subscribe to its `Closing` event.

You can show it as necessary, and when the user "closes" it, you can actually cancel the close and just hide it instead. If they press the button repeatedly, the Form will only show at most once.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private ADCs ADCsdiag = new ADCs();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ADCsdiag.Closing += (sender, eventArgs) =>
            {
                eventArgs.Cancel = true;
                ((ADCs)sender).Hide();
            };
    }

    private void pictureBox18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ADCsdiag.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by holding on to the form instance in a local variable and instantiating it when needed:

```
private ADCs _ADCsdiag;

private void pictureBox18_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (_ADCsdiag == null) { 
      _ADCsdiag = new ADCs(); 
      _ADCsdiag.Closed += (s, e) =>
       {
          _ADCsdiag= null;
        };
   }
   ADCsdiag.Show();
}
```